# How to convert a matrix to square matrix by appending 0's

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a list of matrices of various sizes. For example:

```
97x347 uint8

63x57 uint8

97x225 uint8

73x249 uint8

49x200 uint8

64x278 uint8
```

I need to convert them to a square matrix. I looked into `reshape` but it is not what I am looking for as I need the arrangement of the data to remain undisturbed. These should be converted to a square matrix by appending 0's to the rows and columns.

Is it possible to achieve this? Loss of data is not an issue, so if some rows and columns are to be removed to achieve this target, that will not affect my end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since writing outside matrix bounds will extend it, it's as simple as

```
function a=squarify(a);
[m n]=size(a);
if m==n; return; end
a( max(m,n) , max(m,n) ) = 0
```

Comment: Thats very helpful. Thank you. However is there a way to divide the padding between both sides? For example in the matrix of size ''97*347`` all 0's are padded starting from row 98 onwards. Is it possible to divide this padding between both sides?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `padarray`.

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6];
B = padarray(A,[1,0], 'post')
B =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     0     0     0
```

Here's the link to its documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html